# Reordering Div like source reordering

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am using two divisions.(Both height is set to Auto).

Now, in mobile view, I want the left view to be 100% width and at bottom and right view to be 100% and on top; how can achieve this?

If I give `margin-left:100%` to left and `margin-left:-100% to right` they just go off-screen, and the horizontal scroll bar shows in browser.

Here is the
[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/wbu512r3/)

[image: Image showing current, and desired, outcome]

Comment: Have you tried to use `position:relative` ?

Comment: no that does not work..

Comment: still divs going on right side with horizontal scrollbar

Comment: Tried @media? Something like http://www.zell-weekeat.com/how-to-write-mobile-first-css/

Comment: @Murai ok i will look at it but please tell me a solution;

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using the same exact HTML. Only the CSS is changing and this can be done with media-queries.

```css
html, body{ height:100%; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0 }

#red{ 
  background:red; height:40%; width:50%; float:left;
} 

#yellow{ 
  background:yellow; height:40%; width:50%; float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="yellow"></div><div id="red"></div>
```

```css
html, body{ height:100%; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0 }

#red{ 
  background:red; height:40%; width:100%; 
} 

#yellow{ 
  background:yellow; height:40%; width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="yellow"></div><div id="red"></div>
```

**EDIT:** Use the following code if you want them flipped.

```css
html, body{ height:100%; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0 }

#red{ 
  background:red; height:40%; width:100%; 
  position:relative;
  top:-40%;
} 

#yellow{ 
  background:yellow; height:40%; width:100%;
  position:relative;
  top:40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="yellow"></div><div id="red"></div>
```

Comment: What to do if i wat right on top and left on Bottom

Comment: thanks but what if its responsive and i dont know the heights. i mean its auto height like in a framework?

Comment: No problem. Remember that you can always set the height you want with media queries.

Comment: No imean how to do if the height is auto. i want it auto?

Comment: Can you link me to a fiddle or something so I can see what you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74517/discussion-between-lynel-hudson-and-marc-andre-jiacarrini).